# jqgrid date time field time is not showing correctly while deploy on server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

Hello every one I have a strange issue, I am working on MVC 4 and I have a grid in which I am showing date and time. But some how time is not showing correctly in that field. It shows the time after adding 4 hour to time only when it is deployed on server. But if I run the application on local machine it shows time correctly as it was in database.

Following is the date stored in database.

[image: date stored in database]

but while in i run it on deployed server it shows time different as in the image.
[image]

This is how i format the cell in the grid.
`formatoptions: { 'srcformat' : 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 'newformat' : 'h:i A d/m/Y ' }` 
I didn't understand what is wrong with the deployed server. I also tried to used non minified Js of `jqgrid.local-en.js` and also tried to publish the site again on server but it didn't resolve the issue. please suggest something sorry for my bad English and question description.

Comment: Timezone difference between you and the server perhaps?

Comment: Do you get the same issue on the server if you *do not* apply formatting (in other words, just show the date as it's stored in the db?) Is there any additional manipulation being done to these `dates` that isn't indicated in your question?

Comment: @pendo yes there is a timezone difference between local and server its -5 hours from local cause server is UK based but when i create a new record from server it add the correct time in database according to server but it didn't display it correctly it add 4 hours in that time.

Comment: @wahwahwah i didn't try it without the formatting but i will now. And no additional manipulations are done on the fields it shows it as it is.

Comment: 1) please post in *all questions* about jqGrid the information about **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and **the fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). 2) It's important to know whether your *server code* return local time or UTC. It's recommended to use [ISO 8601](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format 3) There are really many scenarios with dates. One can't say that someone is wrong or not. You can use the settings based of your requirements.

Comment: @Oleg sorry for the late comment but i think i am using an older version of jqgrid its 4.6.0 and server returns its local time which will same as UTC as its a UK based server(I think so ). I  used ISO 8601 format too.

Comment: @jazzb: Try to use ISO date with `z` (UTC time), like 2017-05-17T18:21:41Z. Additionally you can use `userLocalTime: true` property of `formatoptions`. The property exists only starting with version version 4.7 and not exist in version 4.6. I'd strictly recommend you to upgrade to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.14.0. It's the fork of jqGrid, which I develop. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html), [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and READMEs to previously published versions.

Comment: Thanks every one for giving some thought about the issue i had it resolved it was server time settings which was messing with the time fields I had it fix thanks